# Strange Google Results after Websites Server Change

Tags: dns, seo, server, redirect

I have two eCommerce websites,
for eg.
1. www.abc.com 
2. www.abc.co.uk

Previously, both sites were on US server. We have shifted them to Indian Server and Redesign both websites. At the start we didn't redirect all urls to the new website, after two days, old urls redirection was complete to the new urls for www.abc.com.

Now problem is when I search for my domain name in Google.co.uk , It shows me www.abc.co.uk website in search results but WITH META TITLE and DESCRIPTION of www.abc.com website. How it can be possible ? Does Google consider both websites as the same? How can other website title appear to another website? Does changing server or bad URL redirection create such issues? Also, I have restricted UK website only for UK Region, and did the redirection of the .com website to .co.uk if anyone opens the .com website in UK region vice versa

My .co.uk site was ranking on every related keyword, but now ranking has been disturbed badly.

Please share your answers

Answer (score 0):

Changing server is surely not the issue. Bad redirection is a possible cause, wrong canonical links too. Redesign could explain ranking disturbance. Redirection can explain temporary ranking disturbance (not permanent).

Eventually, report this in Google's Webmaster Tool forum.